# Jquery get value of previos element not work

Tags: jquery

Hi i try to get value of table col with jquery
try using prev() function but this stil not work

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>phone:</td>
        <td class="phone">0525671341</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>phone 2:</td>
        <td class="phone2">053211341</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>email:</td>
        <td class="email">test@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editUser" >edit <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.editUser').on('click',function() {
   var email=$(this).prev(".email").text();
   alert (email);
   });
});
```

Comment: the button and the `td` containing the email aren't at the same level.

Comment: How do you think I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal is that the `<td class="email">` is not the previous element.

The simple fix is to change:

```
var email=$(this).prev(".email").text();
```

to:

(update)
Since you mentioned having multiple tables. Assuming there is the same table/hr/button element order, then this should work:

```
var email=$(this).prev().prev().find('.email').text();
// the first prev() is the <hr> tag.
// the second prev() is the <table> tag.
// then find the element with the email class and get the text()
```

Try the runnable example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.editUser').on('click',function() {
   var email=$(this).prev().prev().find('.email').text();
   alert (email);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>phone:</td>
        <td class="phone">0525671341</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>phone 2:</td>
        <td class="phone2">053211341</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>email:</td>
        <td class="email">test@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editUser" >edit <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
```

Comment: Yes that way it works
But I have some such tables for each user and after a table there is the button
If I use your method then a function takes me all the emails from all the tables

Comment: Ok, assuming that you have the same table/hr/button elements used the same way for edits, try the updated example.